# How to hide/show a div when a specific class gets detected (upon scroll)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a sticky header that after scrolling down gets an additional `.header-scrolled` class. I want to change the logo in the header when it's scrolled down.

Here is my simplified HTML:

```
<header class=".header-sticky">
  <div class="logo1">
    <img src="../image1.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="logo2">
    <img src="../image2.jpg">
  </div>
</header>
```

How could I make the entire `<div class="logo2">` not show until `.header-scrolled` class is detected in the `<header>` and reversly - hide `<div class="logo1">` and show `<div class="logo2">` when the respective class in the header appears after scroll?

Comment: You tagged this with JavaScript, so I assume you're already using it to add/remove the `header-scolled` class? You can use the same code to also show/hide those logo divs. Add your JS to the question please.

Answer (score 2):

By using CSS, no need to use JavaScript:

```
.logo1 { display: block; }
.logo2 { display: none; }

.header-scrolled .logo1 { display: none; }
.header-scrolled .logo2 { display: block; }
```

BTW: It looks like your `.header-sticky` class attribute should be `header-sticky` (no dot in front) inside your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css to `display` on your elements by targetting the elements through their respective classes

See working example below:

```js
const changeClass = function() {
  let elem = document.getElementsByClassName('header-sticky')[0].className = "header-scrolled";
}
```

```css
.header-sticky .logo1 {
  display: block;
}

.header-sticky .logo2 {
  display: none;
}

/* When header-sticky changes to header-scrolled change the displays arround */

.header-scrolled .logo1 {
  display: none;
}

.header-scrolled .logo2 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<header class="header-sticky">
  <div class="logo1">
    <img src="../image1.jpg" alt="Logo1">
  </div>
  <div class="logo2">
    <img src="../image2.jpg" alt="Logo2">
  </div>
  
  <button onclick="changeClass()">Change to scrolled</button>
</header>
```